# SQL Injection protect using MVC - The Stored Procedures included Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security, entity-framework-5

One of my clients using Dynamic SQL as part of the stored procedures. they don't want to change this. I am building MVC Website that should use that risky stored procedures. therefore, using parameters with Entity Framework will not solve the problem.

When i used the old and good SQL helper, i checked all the parameters inside the ExecuteQuery function and tried to find risky keywords. but now, when i'm using the native .NET Entity Framework 5 i have no shared function i can check there for that.

Using validators for every specific field is not good for me. is there an option to make overadding function for the Entity Framework part which execute the SP or Any other ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: I don't know about EF5, but in general there is no quick fix. Scanning for blacklisted keywords is almost a complete waste of time—either you will be blocking perfectly legit words people are likely to use (eg `OR`), or you will be missing a wide variety of attacks. Probably both.

Comment: Inspect the stored procedure code and see what kinds of injection you've got. If it's only injection into string literals then banning the use of the apostrophe in all forms of input would be your first step. If they're injecting unquoted vars for integers, ensure all such fields really are integers. If they are column names, lock down input to known-good values. It's a crappy, unscalable, fragile way to develop, but if you really can't change existing broken code it's all you've got. :-(

Comment: Another thing you could do is to escape apostrophes in all inputs into dynamic code as replace([parameter], "'", "''"), then were there to be an sql injection attack, the single quote is escaped, and the whole value gets treated as a string and persisted, without doing what it is intended to do.

Comment: I would generally avoid doing escapes on input. Even ignoring the mangling you get from it when you use the input in a different context to the context that needs the escaping, it's not necessarily watertight. For example if a string gets replaced, sliced or (most commonly, often implicitly) truncated after the `'`->`''` escape it may be possible to discard one of the apostrophes, opening the potential for another field in the same query to do an injection.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of how the dynamic SQL query is constructed within an SP?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say whether the dynamic SQL within the stored procedures uses parameters or not. Assuming not, the best solution would be to encode strings for single quotes **at the point of query execution**

e.g. create a method`string EncodeSqlString(string s) { return s.replace("'", "''"); }`

Then call this method

```
cmd.CommandText = "SP_FOO";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
EntityParameter param = new EntityParameter();
param.Value = EncodeSqlString(myString);
param.ParameterName = "MyParam";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

This would be the safest way as you are only encoding the string values as passed to the stored procedure, you are not using the values elsewhere and in contexts where the quote encoding isn't appropriate, and you will be mitigating the risk of truncation (as long as there is no truncation happening within the SPs). This will also only work correctly if the SPs only use the values for constructing SQL queries - if they do anything else with them then this probably isn't the way to go.

Only pass string values into this method. For other, non-quoted types you should ensure that they are the correct type before passing them into the parameter. e.g. for an `int`

```
  string number = Request.QueryString["Number"];
    if (int.TryParse(number, out myInt))
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "SP_BAR";
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      EntityParameter param = new EntityParameter();
      param.Value = myInt;
      param.ParameterName = "MyParam";
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
    else
    {
      // handle appropriately but do not use value
    }
```